# Cannot add key to kernel keyring

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, ecryptfs

I have an encrypted folder that I want to decrypt (using ecryptfs). I went over all the standard procedures mentioned [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10208094&postcount=15).
Everything seems to go well (getting passphrase, then adding it a keyring and finally attempting to mount using ecrptfs) until I try to mount. It fails saying file not found.
`dmesg` says following:

```
[   66.412772] Could not find key with description: [xxxx]
[   66.412776] process_request_key_err: No key
[   66.412778] Could not find valid key in user session keyring for sig specified in mount option: [xxxx]
[   66.412780] One or more global auth toks could not properly register; rc = [-2]
[   66.412783] Error parsing options; rc = [-2]
```

Based on [this](http://ecryptfs.sourceforge.net/ecryptfs-faq.html#keyproblem) I figure that there is a problem adding the key to the keyring.
Note that I can launch a live usb session, follow the same procedure and make it work. However I'd really love to do anytime and not from the live session.

Comment: Assuming this is with `ecryptfs`; This is crucial information. Why don't you post what you _do_?

Comment: I use the procedure described here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10208094&postcount=15 (of course, i change locations of my encrypted home)

Answer (score -1):

Could you post

```
uname -a
lsb_release -a
lsmod
```

Perhaps

```
modprobe ecryptfs
modprobe aes
modprobe md5
```

could help as it is.

Comment: here u go: http://pastebin.com/mL7qyndb After adding the modules, i tried again to decrypt with the same luck :/

Comment: nothing appears on dmesg or /var/log/messages

Comment: (a) did you try `modprobe`-ing in three steps (see edit)? (b) could you post the result of `dpkg --status ecryptfs-utils` and `debsums -s ecryptfs-utils`

Comment: (a) yes i did :)  (b) http://pastebin.com/78w69P4p